# Htaccess rule with two parameters

Tags: regex, .htaccess

I have a problem about ReWriteRule. My htaccess is:

```
ReWriteRule ^(.*)-about-page/?$ index.php?page=testpage&country=$1 [L]
ReWriteRule ^(.*)-(.*)-about-page/?$ index.php?page=testpage&country=$1&city=$2 [L]
```

if link like this: http://www.example.com/countryname-about-page/ working good. But didn't work when link was like this: http://www.example.com/countryname-cityname-about-page/
city= did come empty and country= did come with city (country=countryname-cityname)

How can I fix?

My second question is:
How can I use one ReWriteRule for this instead of two ReWriteRule?

```
ReWriteRule ^(.*)(-(.*)-?)-about-page/?$ index.php?page=testpage&country=$1&city=$3 [L]
```

1) http://www.example.com/countryname-about-page/ (404 not found)

2) http://www.example.com/countryname-cityname-about-page/ (worked)

Comment: Does this work? `RewriteRule ^(.*)(?:-(.*))?-about-page/?$ index.php?page=testpage&country=$1&city=$3 [L]`

Comment: Can't edit typo: `$2` instead of `$3` there

Comment: @SparK thank you for answer. Worked for 1 and 2 urls. But second url city parameter did come empty again. City parameter coming in country parameter with - character (country=countryname-cityname) How can do (country=countryname) and (city=cityname)

Comment: I changed to $2 instead of $3 and result is same  (country=countryname-cityname)

Comment: Tested it here and posted an answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might want to avoid capturing dashes `-` in the first capture group and making the second optional like so:

```
RewriteRule ^([^-]*)(?:-(.*))?-about-page/?$ index.php?page=testpage&country=$1&city=$2 [L]
```

- The first capture group `([^-]*)` captures any character that isn't dash;
- The second is a non-capturing group `?:` that is simply there so we can signal it's optional at the end with `?`;
- The third capture group catches anything left after a dash and before `-about-page`: `(.*)`.

This is the result:
[image: Results showing the parsed parameters]

Comment: Now two urls and two parameters worked true. Thank you for answer and helpful explanation information about what causes the problem and - character info.